# Why ":first" in jquery .on() selector doesn't always work?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have a special scenario needs to bind events dynamically on the first of child elements with certain class. For example I have one div:

```
<div></div>
```

Then I bind click event on its first '.button' child element:

```
$('div').on('click', '.button:first', function (event) {
    alert($(event.target).text());
});
```

And the child elements will be created later:

```
$('div').append(
    "<span class='button'>Button1</span>" +
    "<span class='button'>Button2</span>");
```

In this case, when Button1 is clicked, it will pop up alert window. Button2 won't. That is correct,... until I put one '.button' element on top of the div.

```
<span class='button'>Outer Button</span>
<div></div>
```

Then clicking on Button1 would never trigger the alert window.
The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/D2H92/

Any idea why this doesn't always work, and how to solve it? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:first` only gets the first element matching the current selector - in this case, the first element matching `.button`. Even though the event is bound to `<div>` elements, that doesn't make the selector only look at that `div` for targets.

Try using `:first-child` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A higher version of jQuery will deal with this.
**[See the fixed bug here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11315)**.

***[Check it](http://jsfiddle.net/D2H92/2/)*** (*change the jQuery version to 1.8.3*).

```
// ..same code
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that but don't know why. Maybe necessary to upgrade jQuery code to latest now, still using 1.7.2. Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the :first or :last pseudo property, then it only works with jQuery 1.8.3 or higher. If you want all the buttons inside of your div (by omitting the :first after the button class) then it works with earlier versions of jQuery. So, in your jsfiddle example you selected jQuery 1.7.2 but you have to switch to at least version 1.8.3

Hope that answered your question.